# Dynamic items on JavaFX interface

Tags: java, user-interface, interface-builder, javafx-2

I am looking to build an application similar to [Blocky](http://code.google.com/p/blockly/).
For that I will be using JavaFX. I am working on prototypes atm. It appears that JavaFX UIs are generally made using Scene Builders. I am still not sure how much flexibility is this going to provide me, when I will be looking to dynamically change shapes (make them bigger etc) during runtime, detect collisions to connect shapes etc.

Could someone more experienced using this technology tell me how feasible an application like this is using JavaFX? Also would it be easier/same to do it with Java? 
Thanks.

Comment: It is completely possible to do it in JavaFX. You can create all your screen components dynamically. JavaFX is a part of Java that allows you to create rich user interfaces. If you are interested in learning it, there are various books and web tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just wasn't sure if it was good choice or if I should stick to Java. It looks like once I get past the learning curve it may prove better.

Comment: Well, actually, it is not a choice between Java and JavaFX. JavaFX sits on top of Java, providing the special capabilities that you need to build your rich user interface. With Java alone, you would not be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turned out to be possible, although a bit tricky. In some cases I would programatically change the dimensions of the shapes when I needed to, after loading them from fxml. This process was not as clean as I would hope but did work.